# Passando atributos para o viewport através de CSS

Tags: html, css, html-meta-tag, viewport

Quais são os modelos de atributos que podemos passar para o viewport através de CSS?

Pegando um exemplo do atributo `content` da meta tag `<viewport></viewport>`: `user-scalable=no`, como eu introduziria isso no modelo abaixo, por exemplo:

```
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: device-width;
}
```

Eu li [isso aqui](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/), mas não entendi muito bem como devo usar isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sei que não é exatamente a resposta que vc queria, **mas talvez justamente por estar deprecado** é que não é possível aplicar atributos como `user-scalable=no` já que não há mais suporte ou atualizações para essa `at rule`

Mas vc pode usar o `min-zoom` e `max-zoom` para tentar limitar a escala, ex:

```
@viewport {
  zoom: 1;
  min-zoom: 100%;
  max-zoom: 100%;
}
```

Tenha ciência que:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Este recurso não é mais recomendado. Embora alguns navegadores ainda possam suportá-lo, ele pode já ter sido removido dos padrões da web relevantes, pode estar em processo de exclusão ou pode ser mantido apenas para fins de compatibilidade. Evite usá-lo e atualize o código existente, se possível; consulte a tabela de compatibilidade na parte inferior desta página para orientar sua decisão. Esteja ciente de que esse recurso pode parar de funcionar a qualquer momento.

**Fonte:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport

Além disso, a `<meta name="viewport">` vai fazer o *override* do `@viewport`, então se vc está tentando sobrescrever via CSS algo que está no *meta viewport*  do HTML vc não vai conseguir.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.